# Flutter : How to not rebuild screen from start in bottom navigation bar and save the last state?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

How to not rebuild the screen from start in the bottom navigation bar and saving the last state of it and if the state of the screen is changed like the driver app has 4 screens and I want the screen of home that contains button Offline Now or Online Now not change the state if I move to another screen, I used a Tabviewbar

What is the solution?

Main Screen class

```
import 'package:drivers_app/tabsPages/earnings_tab_screen.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/tabsPages/home_tab_screen.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/tabsPages/profile_tab_screen.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/tabsPages/zones_tab_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  static const String mainScreenId = "mainScreenId";

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
{
  TabController? tabController;

  int selectedIndex = 0;

  void onItemClicked(int index)
  {
    setState(()
    {
      selectedIndex = index;
      tabController!.index = selectedIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    tabController!.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold
    (
      body: TabBarView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: tabController,
        children:
        [
          HomeScreen(),
          EarningsScreen(),
          ZonesScreen(),
          ProfileScreen(),
        ],
        //index: selectedIndex,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items:
        [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
              ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.credit_card,
              ),
            label: 'Earnings',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.settings_input_antenna_rounded,
              ),
            label: 'Zones',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
              ),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
        ],
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12.0
        ),
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: onItemClicked,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Home Screen Class

```
import 'package:drivers_app/shared/components/components.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_geofire/flutter_geofire.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 15,
  );

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();

  GoogleMapController? newcontrollerGoogleMap;

  var geoLocator = Geolocator();

  String driverStatusText = 'Offline Now - Go Online ';

  Color driverStatusColor = Colors.black;

  bool isDriverAvailable = false;


  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentDriverInfo();
  }

  void locatePosition() async
  {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng latLatPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: latLatPosition, zoom: 14);
    newcontrollerGoogleMap!.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    String Address = await AssistantMethods.searchCoordinateAddress(position, context);
    print("This is your Address :: " + Address);

  }


  void getCurrentDriverInfo() async
  {
    currentfirebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    
    driversRef.child(currentfirebaseUser!.uid).once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
      if(dataSnapshot.value != null)
      {
        driversInformation = Drivers.fromSnapshot(dataSnapshot);
      }
    });
    
    PushNotificationService pushNotificationService = PushNotificationService();

    pushNotificationService.initialize(context);
    pushNotificationService.getToken().toString();
    
    AssistantMethods.retrieveHistoryInfo(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Stack(
      children:
      [
        GoogleMap(
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          initialCameraPosition: HomeScreen._kGooglePlex,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
            newcontrollerGoogleMap = controller;
            _determinePosition();
          },
        ),

        //online offline driver container
        Container(
          height: 140.0,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.black54,
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 60.0,
          left: 0.0,
          right: 0.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children:
            [
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 16.0,
              ),
                child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: ()
                  {
                    if(isDriverAvailable != true)
                    {
                      makeDriverOnlineNow();
                      getLocationLiveUpdates();

                      setState(()
                      {
                        driverStatusColor = Colors.green;
                        driverStatusText = 'Online Now ';
                        isDriverAvailable = true;
                      });
                      displayToast('you are Online Now', context);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      displayToast('you are Offline Now', context);
                      setState(()
                      {
                        driverStatusColor = Colors.black;
                        driverStatusText = 'Offline Now - Go Online ';
                        isDriverAvailable = false;
                      });
                      makeDriverOfflineNow();
                      Appclosed();
                    }
                  },
                  color: driverStatusColor,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0,),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          driverStatusText,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.phone_android,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 26.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Main class

```
import 'package:drivers_app/config_maps.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/modules/car_info_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/Data_Handler/app_Data.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/modules/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/modules/main_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/modules/register_screen.dart';

//Receive message when app is in background solution for on message
Future<void> backgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async
{
  print(message.data.toString());
  print(message.notification!.title);
}


void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);


  currentfirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

DatabaseReference adminRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("admin");
DatabaseReference driversRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers");
DatabaseReference newRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Ride Request");
DatabaseReference rideRequestRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("drivers").child(currentfirebaseUser!.uid).child("newRide");
DatabaseReference availableDriverRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("availableDrivers");
DatabaseReference availableDriverRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("availableDrivers2").child(currentfirebaseUser!.uid);


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create:(context) => AppData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Driver App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        initialRoute: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null ? LoginScreen.loginScreenId : MainScreen.mainScreenId,
        routes:{
          RegisterScreen.registerScreenId: (context)=> RegisterScreen(),
          LoginScreen.loginScreenId: (context)=> LoginScreen(),
          MainScreen.mainScreenId: (context)=> MainScreen(),
          CarInfoScreen.carinfoScreen: (context)=> CarInfoScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use Appbar to place the toggle switch. here only the portion of body changes

Comment: @ismailfarisi what is the solution in my code??

Comment: easiest solution for your problem will be using package like go_router. read the documentation https://gorouter.dev/navigator-builder , you can see a similar use case there

Comment: @ismailfarisi can you tell me how to use this package in my code please

Comment: share ur github repo, I'll share it there. its difficult to show it here. you need updation in the MaterialApp widget

Comment: @ismailfarisi do you want the main code of all screens? .. I upload the main class

Comment: if i need to recreate everything it's lot of work. if you want you can do a video call sharing your screen

Comment: @ismailfarisi ok I accept to make a video call across zoom?

Comment: @ismailfarisi I send you connect on linkedin

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PageView` and `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` on each page/portion (item in the `PageView`) and set `wantToKeepAlive` to true.

For example:

If we have 2 portions, `HomePortion` and `SettingsPortion` like so:

```
class HomePortion extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePortion({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePortionState createState() => _HomePortionState();
}

class _HomePortionState extends State<HomePortion>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return const Center(
      child: Text("Home"),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

```
class SettingsPortion extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingsPortion({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SettingsPortionState createState() => _SettingsPortionState();
}

class _SettingsPortionState extends State<HomePortion>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return const Center(
      child: Text("Settings"),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

> Notice `@override bool get wantKeepAlive => true;` in both portions.

We can then use them in the `Page` like so:

```
class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (index) {
          _controller.jumpToPage(index);
          setState(() {
            _pageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        currentIndex: _pageIndex,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings_rounded),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: PageView(
        children: const [
          HomePortion(),
          SettingsPortion(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  int _pageIndex = 0;
  PageController _controller = PageController();
}
```

Comment: how to make it in my code?

Comment: The all screens is not statefull widget

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget
{
  static const String mainScreenId = "mainScreenId";

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
{
  TabController? tabController;

  int selectedIndex = 0;
  bool online = false;

  void onItemClicked(int index)
  {
    setState(()
    {
      selectedIndex = index;
      tabController!.index = selectedIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    tabController!.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold
    (
      appbar: AppBar(
        actions:[
          Text("online "),
          Switch(
           onChanged:(value){setState((){
                  online = value
                   });}   ,
           value: online       
         )]
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: tabController,
        children:
        [
          HomeScreen(),
          EarningsScreen(),
          ZonesScreen(),
          ProfileScreen(),
        ],
        //index: selectedIndex,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items:
        [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
              ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.credit_card,
              ),
            label: 'Earnings',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.settings_input_antenna_rounded,
              ),
            label: 'Zones',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
                Icons.person,
              ),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
        ],
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black54,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12.0
        ),
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        onTap: onItemClicked,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I not use App bar in my Home screen .. this is my code in home screen (Offline or Online)

Comment: i updated the code can you give me the solution again please?