# In navigate from a first page back to a navbar which works ok, but when i go back to the navbar the maths i have done in the first_page disapear's

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

New code no errors now nut state changes when you leave page (or use the "Back" button) The new code works fine with everything else except pages changes resets adding data sums thanks for helping..

```
    // TODO Implement this library.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tca/navbar.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: AddTwoNumbers()));
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddTwoNumbers({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddTwoNumbers> createState() => _AddTwoNumbersState();
}

class _AddTwoNumbersState extends State<AddTwoNumbers>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  List<TextEditingController> roundOneFields = [];
  List<TextEditingController> roundTwoFields = [];
  int roundOneResult = 0;
  int roundTwoResult = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    roundOneFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    roundTwoFields =
        List.generate(20, (index) => TextEditingController(text: '0'));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Twin City Bowmen Score Sheet'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(25))),
      ), // This is how you can add an appBar.
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R1 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundOneFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 24,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 20,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("R2 Target ${index + 1}:"),
                        Flexible(
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8)),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            controller: roundTwoFields[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Add"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      roundOneFields.forEach((e) =>
                          roundOneResult = roundOneResult + int.parse(e.text));
                      roundTwoFields.forEach((e) => roundTwoResult =
                          roundTwoResult + int.parse(e.text.toString()));
                    });
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text("Back"),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Navbar())))
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              "Result \n Round 1: $roundOneResult and Round 2: $roundTwoResult Total = ${roundOneResult + roundTwoResult}",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Thats the end of the code i added the 3 parts of code you need to keep alive state. Sorry writing more because it says i need to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the page rebuild the widget.

Duplicate ? :
[Flutter : How to not rebuild screen from start in bottom navigation bar and save the last state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70929064/flutter-how-to-not-rebuild-screen-from-start-in-bottom-navigation-bar-and-save)

Comment: Thanks Anan, ill look into it. Looks like changing a class that holds the state will take me a bit of time to rework it get back to you thanks. Im Just a newbie

Comment: I have added the whole page with your web page suggested changes but i get errors know can you help please:@Anan Alfred

Comment: what error ? can you show the error message ?

Comment: Just added the whole new "firts_page" page thanks it has no errors but still the state goes back to zero when you navigate pages thanks Anan

Comment: ouh i c. so you want the state keep data right ? 
but after you leave page AddTwoNumbers. or you back to another page then you enter the AddTwoNumbers again, it will reset the data. 

the code inside initState will rebuild and the data will be reset based on logic in initState

you need to implement state management. you can use Provider state management or inherited state. 

the advance one you can use Bloc, GetX, MobX, Redux etc.

Comment: Hi Anan, yes and thank you but shouldnt this code do that as well
with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
super.build(context);
 @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

Comment: No, keep alive just make the page not rebuild while you move between the Tab. I thought you implement navigation bar and want to hold the data while move between Tab. 

so you need to learn the state management.

Comment: Ok thanks Anan so what do you sugust in state management use bloc or do you have any suguestions or example code that might help.

Comment: HI @anan alfred, maybe i getting this all wrong, maybe i should be using screens not navigating to separate .dart pages ..... can i add the code above to a screen (when i say screen/page i mean within the one .dart file) instead of a routing to differnent .dart and loosing my data state. So when you say tabs do you mean screens maybe.
If so can i add my code in the above example into a screen and use the keepalives to hold data state? thanks.

Comment: on your code you have AddTwoNumbers Screen, and the back button is 
```dart
```

Comment: Sorry im confussed what did you mean by the last comment @Anan

Comment: no problem, but still my recommendation is use the State Management. 
that's the only way to manage your data and state